# Anonymous user having user relationships

Tags: 7, views, users

I have come up with a peculiar problem. IO am using the User Relationships module for my Drupal 7 site. The issue is that i had given privileges to the anonymous user to view user profile. The anonymous user however cannot be a part of the user relationship but that user had clicked on that action and now somehow or other when i log in as an authenticated user and see the view which i have created to show me the users who are following me, i see i am followed(the name of the relationship) by an Anonymous user. How can i remove this. i also checked in the databases but i saw nothing regarding this...no request with user id 0. i also have all the correct permissions.

Any Suggestions

Regards

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a very similar issue... Here's the code I used (modified to reflect the affected `$user->uid` as `0`):

```
<?php
$anon_uid = 0;
$admin_uid = 1;
// The next line makes it appear as though the relationship was deleted by the original
// user in the relationship. You might want to change the value though since Anonymous
// should normally be denied access to do this. For example, to make it appear as
// though each of Anonymous's relationship was deleted by user 1, change $anon_uid 
// to $admin_uid (next line ONLY) 
$anon_deletedby = user_load(array('uid' => $anon_uid));
$anon_friends = user_relationships_load(array("user" => $anon_uid));
foreach ($anon_friends as $friend) {
  user_relationships_delete_relationship($friend, $anon_deletedby);
}
?>
```

**PLEASE BE SURE TO BACK UP YOUR DATABASE AND TEST THIS IN A NON-PRODUCTION ENVIRONMENT FIRST.**